# Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: php, paypal, magento-1.9

I lost my mind during deep into Magento.
I need to activate some of Methods (like DebitCard and CreditCard payment) in the Magento shop.
Also I need to deactivate PayPal Express and activate PayPal Standart.
**Issue**:
Magento generates only Paypal Express if I don't activate PayPal Standart or anything doesn't work.
I have DB Access, and of course, I already tried to change payment params in core_config_data table, but in my payment-systems list (ul class="checkout-types" in the checkout/cart/ page) only PayPal Express, but No any other payment system.

I hope that there is someone who can help me in the issue.

[ul.checkout-types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CElY6.png)
[core_config_data table in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iwiq.png)